# Gitlab runner in nixos

Tags: nixos

Since upgrading to nixos 22.11 (from 19.0x) I can't get the gitlab-runners to work.

The docs at "https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Gitlab_runner" are.. mostly unreadable. The old config made sense

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  services.gitlab-runner = {
    enable = true;
    configOptions = {
      concurrent = 4;
      runners = [
        {
          name = "joe-1";
          url = "https://gitlab.com";
          token = "tokentokentoken";
          executor = "docker";
          docker = {
            host = "";
            image = "alpine:latest";
            privileged = true;
            volumes = ["/cache" "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"];
          };
        }
        {
          name = "joe-2";
...
```

This of course doesn't compile anymore. And I have zero idea how to fix it. =(

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the option may have changed since 19.0x. In more recent versions, nixpkgs has taken to a `services.*.settings` model. `settings` options are used when a service has a readable config file: nixpkgs transforms the value into the data format the service requires. It looks as though changing `configOptions` to `settings` may be all that is required.

Comment: Mm. The compiler/linter warned about that so I did end up changing it from configOptions to settings. However, it completely ignore the rest of my settings so all I got was a "empty" toml  in /var/lib/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/config.toml

Comment: What is meant by "empty"? Perhaps your user does not have read permissions for that file?